# Subclasses in Python 2.7

Tags: python, subclass

I'm trying to do something I consider pretty ordinary in Object Oriented programming
but can't find any documentation on it for Python 2.7
I want to create a subclass of a superclass where, when I'm done
superclass
is bound to the superclass
superclass.subclass is bound to the subclass and
subclass is bound to nothing.
Here's the best solution I can come up with:

```
class superclass:
  pass
class subclass(superclass):
  pass
superclass.subclass = subclass
del subclass
```

Sometimes I want subclass to be in its own file, other times not.
Is there a more elgant solution where I don't have to manually perform the
last two lines?
Although

```
class superclass:
  class subclass:
    pass
```

almost does the right thing, subclass doesn't actually inherit from superclass.
And if I try to do:

```
class superclass:
  class subclass(superclass):
    pass
```

I get an error message that superclass is unbound.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The best way is to have both in a module and only import `superclass` if you don't want `subclass` in your namespace.

Comment: This is nothing to do with OOP, perhaps you are porting ideas from another language that forces these kind of perversions

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everyone else that this is a silly thing to do and I don't think you should do it, but in the interest of knowledge:

```
class Superclass(object):
    pass

Superclass.Subclass = type('Subclass', (Superclass,), {
    'foo': lambda self: self,
})
```

where the dictionary argument contains any methods. I don't think there's a nice way to do this with the `class` syntax, but that's really just syntactic sugar for calling `type` anyway.

You don't have to define the methods as `lambda`s; they can be normal functions with `def` as long as they have the `self` argument. You'll probably want to hide their definitions if you do that, though....

Comment: That does answer the question, but surely that's a lot less elegant if the whole point is to save lines...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple class decorator to do the referencing:

```
def refer(cls):
    cls.__bases__[0].subclass = cls
    return cls
```

Here's how you use it:

```
>>> class Superclass:
        pass

>>> @refer
    class Subclass(SuperClass):
        pass
```

You will still need to delete *Subclass* if you don't want the name in the module namespace.

Comment: You'd want `setattr(cls.__bases__[0], cls.__name__, cls)` to assign it to the name of the subclass; this would assign it as the literal name `subclass`, and so only works for one subclass.